# Why i am getting below error in Salesforce LWC playground

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to test some code in LWC playground & is facing below issues.

So, i have not coded anything from my side. Just opened this url:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/e922d55d950b9529e93147cdb945d77b636a6ce9/edit

This is OOB example for datatable implementation. But still, i m getting this error.

Chrome: 
[image: play]

Firefox:
[image]

Comment: Could be a playground issue, do you have same behavior in your org?

Comment: No, It is working properly in my org.

Comment: I'm asking around. A playground example should not break.

Comment: @sfdcfox any luck? Were you able to check this out ?

Comment: @RajendraSinghNagar I've been asked to submit a case. I'm working on it. Thanks for following up!

Comment: I think the playground is operating on a past release, we need to update it to the latest version. We'll try to get that done today.

Comment: Great, Thanks. One more thing (not related to this question), do you know when new release for local development server will be released? Current version requires you to use  @track for primitive types.

Comment: Seems to be working now right?

Comment: Local dev is being worked on currently. (It wasn't for a little while) I think couple weeks was the goal, but Covid really ruined all that.  So not sure at the moment. I've transferred to another project.